# Kivy - How to trigger ModalView from Python code

Tags: python, kivy, modal-view

I want to force the start of a `ModalView` when the app is loaded, but i can not figure out how to do it.

It's working fine when i push the button, but i cant figure out how to trigger the event from the python file.

How can i from the code trigger the event (button)?

KV file

```
<Controller>

    <BoxLayout>

        ***a lot of code ***

        Button:
            id: my_id
            text: "text"
            color: txt_color
            size_hint_y: .05
            background_color: btn_color_not_pressed if self.state=='normal' else btn_color_pressed

            on_release:
                Factory.About().open()

<About@ModalView>
    id: about
    auto_dismiss: True

    
    *** some more code ****
```

How do i call the event from my main.py?

---

*After solution from @john Anderson:*

file: main.py

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.factory import Factory


kivy.require("1.11.1")


class Controller(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Controller, self).__init__()

        Factory.About().open()

class mainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Controller()


mainApp().run()
```

file: main.kv

```
    #:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory


<Controller>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: "THIS IS THE MAIN TEKST"
            color: 1,0,0,1
            size_hint_y:.8
        Button:
            text: "About"
            size_hint_y: .2
            on_release: Factory.About().open()

<About@ModalView>

    size_hint: .8,.5

    BoxLayout
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: self.width, self.height
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}
        size_hint: .8,.6


        Label:
            text: "ABOUT MY APP"
            color: 0,1,0,1
        Button:
            text: "Back"
            size_hint_y: .2
            on_release: root.dismiss()
```

[image]

Comment: Try using `Factory.About().open()` in your main.py.

Comment: @JohnAnderson

Thx for the answer :) :)

That worked with triggering the code ... but made some new problems.

The app and the ModalView seems to be drawn at the same time

I have made an examplecode, and made a screenshot after the app has started, where it can be seen.

It works ... almost :)

Comment: The new example code is in the original question :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `About` `ModalView` is being created in the `__init__()` method of your root `Controller` widget. That means that it is created before your `Controller`. An easy fix is to delay the creation of the `About` widget until after the `App` is started. You can use the `App` method `on_start()` to do that:

```
class Controller(BoxLayout):
    pass


class mainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Controller()

    def on_start(self):
        Factory.About().open()
```